# ctrl c, ctrl v on a DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView, and i want to be able to copy a row from it using CRTL+C.

I have created a event for it, but i keep getting the error "Cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Keys'.

```
AnalysisDGWArray[index].KeyDown += new KeyEventArgs(Copy_Click); 

private void Copy_Click(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.C && e.Control)
    {
        // copy logic
        DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
        dgv.Select();
        DataObject o = dgv.GetClipboardContent();
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(o);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286483/datagridview-cannot-convert-from-method-group-to-keys might be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is this line where you are trying to add the event handler:

```
AnalysisDGWArray[index].KeyDown += new KeyEventArgs(Copy_Click);
```

You get the error because this isn't the correct syntax (you're trying to pass a method - `Copy_Click` - to the `KeyEventArgs` constructor.)

The correct way to wire up the event handler is this:

```
AnalysisDGWArray[index].KeyDown += Copy_Click;
```

Comment: Tnx Mate, Exactly what i needed